# How to remove confirm navigation pop-up in mobile app

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, cordova, mobile-application

[image: Pop up image]

This happens when changes are made and redirecting to other pages especially during login or logout. 
Code for **ondevice ready** is,

```
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    //alert("ready");
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Please suggest a way to hide this native pop up..

Comment: I guess its a custom logic written in your script. To disable this, add window.onbeforeunload = null; in your script

Comment: Please check my script in the description, I have added  window.onbeforeunload = null; @Gandhi

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = null; need not be inside device ready event listener. your device ready listener is getting invoked?

Comment: @Gandhi I added window.onbeforeunload = null; inside the onBackKeyDown function, Now its not showing. Thanks..

Comment: posted the answer. Please accept. Cheers

Comment: was that answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line in your code,

> window.onbeforeunload = null;

This line need not be placed inside deviceready event listener. It can be placed on functions that it called during click of back button or during page reloads.